# Podman run kept trying my proxy which is quitted

Tags: docker, proxy, podman

**The error**

I have a proxy on localhost:8001, however even when I quit the proxy completely

```
 podman run --log-level=trace \                                                 
  -p 9000:9000 \
  -p 9001:9001 \
  minio/minio server /data --console-address ":9001"

Error: initializing source docker://minio/minio:latest: pinging container registry registry-1.docker.io: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8001: connect: connection refused
```

**The env**

Macos Monterey 12.3.1.

Docker desktop Version

```
4.10.0 (82025)

Engine: 20.10.17

Compose: 1.29.2

Credential Helper: v0.6.4

Kubernetes: v1.24.1

Snyk: v1.827.0
```

Podman version 4.1.1

***Trials***

I have tried

1. explicitly setting the proxy in the docker. As in the picture the proxy itself works. ---> trying 8001 does not work

[image]

2. explicitly setting the "manual proxy" and leaving the proxies empty, as described [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9400) ---> still trying 8001

[image]

Can someone help? Devastated.

Comment: Please don't post images of text. How did you set the proxy in podman in the first place? And why are you showing information about your Docker version if you're using Podman?